# Why isn't my array saving the results?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, insert, save

My code has a constructor which inputs the position and integer into the selected position as wished by the user up to and including 20 possible entries.

Then it returns the result as an array from my constructor.... the only issue is that it is not saving the result.

I want it to save the array result as input by the user and ask the user for another input until all slots have been filled but each time they input it it should display the array so far.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arraySize = new int[20];
        while (arraySize.length <= 20){
          System.out.println("Enter the position");
          int arrayPosition = input.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter the integer to be inserted here");
          int positionInteger = input.nextInt();
          int[] arrayThatIsntSavingAnything = Insert(arraySize, arrayPosition, positionInteger);
        }       
          System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arrayThatIsntSavingAnything));
        }
```

Comment: Looks to me like your code won't even compile because `arrayThatIsntSavingAnything` is defined within the while loop and won't be accessible outside it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `arraySize` is always of length 20 irrespective of what is filled in it. Thus, it never enters the `while` loop. You can initiate another counter to keep a track of number of inputs performed. Also, note that, you are performing a check of `<=` which can cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as the `arraySize[20]` does not exist.